# Anyone successfully accepting bitcoin or other cryptocurrency on a commerce site?

Tags: commerce

We're already accepting bitcoin and litecoin in our physical store and would love to add it to our online stores. We tried the Bitpay drupal module but it breaks both our sites. 
Anyone accepting cryptos successfully? How?

Answer (score 1):

If you want a solution where customers can choose from a wide range of cards/currencies to pay with, Stripe integrated with Drupal Commerce is a good way to do so. Here is the module: [Commerce Stripe module](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_stripe)